# Prove that a series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a series which is as follows

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^n-1\right)$$

and I am asked whether it converges or diverges.

I think this series is convergent and I tried to find something greater than this so I can apply the comparison test, but I can't do it.

Please help me on how to approach this, thank you.

Comment: I would note that the expansion of $(1+\frac{1}{n^3})^n$ contains only one term $\geq1$, being $1$ itself. The $-1$ cancels this out and the rest resembles a $p$-series with $p>1$ which we know converges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$\left(1+\frac1{n^3}\right)^n-1=\exp\left(n\ln \left(1+\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)-1\sim_\infty\frac1{n^2}$$
and the Riemann series $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ is convergent. Conclude by comparison.

Comment: About $1.6677$ while $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}\approx 1.6449$.  More than $99\%$ of the difference is in the first nine terms